# Spring security authentication-success-handler-ref is not getting called after successful authentication by CustomAuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-4

I have been trying to migrate from spring 3.2 to 4.1. I am using spring 4 jars. I have been struggling with this task. Spring security authentication-success-handler-ref is not getting called after successful authentication by CustomAuthenticationManager. Even default-target-url is also not working. even after loging I stay on the same page and not getting redirected.

Comment: If authentication is successful, the resulting Authentication object will be placed into the SecurityContextHolder. The configured AuthenticationSuccessHandler will then be called to either redirect or forward the user to the appropriate destination. By default a SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler is used, which means that the user will be redirected to the original destination they requested before they were asked to login.   For me the configured success handler is not getting called